# Why is my argument not defined when invoking a DB call?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, graphql, apollo-server

I am using trying to return a Postgres DB query via a GraphQL resolver. For some reason, `result` is coming back as not defined when I (on purpose) query a row for an ID that doesn't exist. When I console log it, `result` always comes back as expected:

```
result = {
 rows: [],
 ...
}
```

However, when I run it and make a Query, or when I use `node inspect index.js` and let it run until the debugger, it doesn't seem to recognize that `result` is even defined. When I run `console.log(result)` in Node when it hits the debugger, I get this error:

```
debug> console.log(result)
REPL2:1
console.log(result)
            ^

Uncaught ReferenceError: result is not defined
    at REPL2:1:13
    at Script.runInContext (node:vm:139:12)
    at Object.runInContext (node:vm:289:6)
    at REPLServer.controlEval (node:internal/debugger/inspect_repl:578:25)
    at bound (node:domain:421:15)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (node:domain:432:12)
    at REPLServer.onLine (node:repl:898:10)
    at REPLServer.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at REPLServer.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at [_onLine] [as _onLine] (node:internal/readline/interface:424:12)
```

and when I run the query from the Playground, I get this error:

```
/Users/user/Projects/geolocatr_api/db/queries/user.queries.js:21
          id: user.id,
                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
    at /Users/user/Projects/geolocatr_api/db/queries/user.queries.js:21:20
    at Query.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Projects/geolocatr_api/node_modules/pg-pool/index.js:417:18)
    at Query.handleReadyForQuery (/Users/user/Projects/geolocatr_api/node_modules/pg/lib/query.js:138:12)
    at Client._handleReadyForQuery (/Users/user/Projects/geolocatr_api/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:290:19)
    at Connection.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at /Users/user/Projects/geolocatr_api/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:114:12
    at Parser.parse (/Users/user/Projects/geolocatr_api/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:40:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Projects/geolocatr_api/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)

Node.js v18.0.0
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I'm really not sure why my console logs seem to see that something is there, but Node doesn't. Otherwise, when an ID that exists in the table is passed in, it works as expected.

The code:

```
// Resolver

  Query: {
    user: ( _, { id } ) => {
      console.log({id}); // Node recognizes this as the correct number
      return getUserById(id);
    },
  },


// DB Query Function

const getUserById = (id) => {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    db.query(
      `
        SELECT id, first_name, email, phone
        FROM users
        WHERE id = $1;
      `,
      [id],
      function(err, result) {
        // debugger; // Result comes back as not defined
        if (!result.rows) { // Will not run this if block
          console.log(result.rows);
          reject("Could not find user.");
        }
        if (err) reject(err);
        const user = rows[0];

        resolve({
           id: user.id,
           firstName: user.first_name,
           email: user.email,
           phone: user.phone,
        });
      }
    );
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically with those `(err, result) => { ... }` callbacks, you check `err` **first** because if it is *truthy*, there's a good chance that the second argument will not be defined.

You should also `return` after detecting an error to prevent the rest of your callback from executing.

FYI, [node-postgresl](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries) supports promises natively so there's no need to explicitly create one. Below I've translated your code to an async function to take advantage of this.

```js
const getUserById = async (id) => {
  const { rows } = await db.query({
    text: "SELECT id, first_name as firstName, email, phone FROM users WHERE id = $1",
    values: [id],
  });

  // `rows` is always an array so check the length
  if (rows.length !== 1) {
    throw new Error(`Could not find user by id [${id}]`);
  }

  return rows[0];
};
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked almost perfectly! Interestingly, it didn't keep `firstName` in camel case as you wrote it, but that was an easy enough fix.

Also, I originally did check for `err` first, but because it wasn't hitting I figured maybe there wasn't an actual error being passed in and I needed to check if result existed first.

Comment: @aapiane09 did you add `first_name as firstName`? Doesn't really matter if you fixed it another way though

Comment: Yes, but the returned object had the key `firstname`. I just ended up removing the `as firstName` and changing my GQL User typedef from camel case to snake case so that it's the same in all places (instead of different conventions in the DB and how was going to define it on the client), and it started working again.

Comment: That's weird. I wouldn't expect PG to change the alias case. Anyway, glad you sorted it out